# Will Facebook SDK 3.1.x display authentication page?

Tags: php, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-canvas

I am doing a Canvas app inside the facebook page.

My very simple question is this:  With the newest facebook SDK (just downloaded today), if a user has not yet granted access permission to your app, will the facebook class within the SDK automatically determine that and attempt to get authorization?

I can manually get auth for my app by going here:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<myClientID>&redirect_uri=<myRedirectURL>&type=user_agent&display=page&scope=publish_stream,%20user_about_me,%20user_likes,%20email
```

That all works just fine... but when I attempt to do what the example.php does in the SDK, it returns an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /public_html/bridge/base_facebook.php on line 1107

Thus my question is: Am I supposed to be getting a valid OAuth access token, or am I setting up the facebook PHP SDK wrong?

Here is my complete PHP code that generates the error:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'app_id' => '<my app id>',
'app_secret' => '<my app secret>',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$jared = $facebook->api('/jaredmark');

if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

This code is essentially a direct copy/paste from the example, with a few minor edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be the case that the PHP SDK will display an authentication pop up without you manually causing it to do so by redirecting to that specific page.  *sigh*